# C# ASPNet - Message Box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a message box with just an "OK" button.
When the user presses OK I want the page to be refreshed 
back to the original state.

Message Box Code:

```
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGAUGE='JavaScript'>alert('Donation Successful')</SCRIPT>");
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a redirect in javascript to your page, try something like this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<script language='JavaScript'>
                      alert('Donation Successful'); 
                      location.href='www.yoursite.com/page.aspx'; </script>");
```

Just replace the url in `location.href` to a valid url to your page.